# Problem with hiding TextView below another View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I am making chatting app and I do not know how can I hide text below other View, here is photo: [phone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycCsb.png).

Here is my XML code:

```
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

         <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/darker_sky_blue"
android:theme="@style/MyTheme.StatusBarColor.darker_sky_blue"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And I am adding text programmatically with this code:

```
                          LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.chatMessages);

                                    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                                    textView.setText(oneLine);

                                    textView.setTextSize(25);

                                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));

                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    params.setMargins(10,0,10,0);
                                    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

                                    linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

So, how can I get the result I want?

Comment: So, actually when you scrolling scrollview that time text goes outside right?

Comment: How are you getting the rounded corners. Are they coming from the background for the ScrollView?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes rounded corners are made in scroll view background

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya yes

Comment: Why don't you use materialCardView and add to it rounded corners

Comment: try to add 
android:background="@color/darker_sky_blue" 
in your linear Layout.

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya it makes whole background at this color

Comment: you given radius to your scrollview right? then you also need to give same radius to child or inner layout, Which is LinearLayout in your case.

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya how can I add radius to LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Add `CardView` as parent of `ScrollView`. Set background color to card using `app:cardBackgroundColor` and Set corner to Card using `app:cardCornerRadius`

Try this code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#7CCAEA"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chatMessages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your background has the corners you need to set [android:clipToOutline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:clipToOutline) to true for the *ScrollView*. (You could also move the background to the *LinearLayout* and set the attribute there.)

```
android:clipToOutline="true"
```

This will clip the text the way you want, except it actually won't since there is a bug in Android Studio so this attribute cannot be entered.

As a work-around do the following:

**For Kotlin:**

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.scroll).clipToOutline = true
```

**For Java:**

```
findViewById(R.id.scroll).setClipToOutline(true);
```

Applies to API 21+.

Comment: @Igorson Cannot resolve where? In the code or the XML? The XML is documented but does not work (see answer.) You will have to do it in code.

Comment: In code I did findViewById<View>(R.id.scroll).clipToOutline = true; and it is giving me that error, and also why are you adding <View> ?

Comment: @Igorson I added the Java version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make XML file in drawable folder.

   ```
            <shape
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle"   >

                <solid
                    android:color="darker_sky_blue" >
                </solid>

                <corners
                    android:radius="11dp"   > <!--  give radius same as in scrollview -->
                </corners>

            </shape>
   ```
2. Add to your LinearLayout.

   ```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chatMessages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: Now i get something like this: https://imgur.com/a/rEeQCyg

Comment: I think your problem is in Java coding, Because I tried your code it work fine without adding drawable in LinearLayout.